# Output two columns for 1 field for different date ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table "ITM_SLS" with the following fields:

```
ITEM
DESCRIPTION
TRANSACTION #
DATE
QTY SOLD
```

I want to be able to output QTY SOLD for a one month value and a year to date value so that the output would look like this:

```
ITEM, DESCRIPTION, QTY SOLD MONTH, QTY SOLD YEAR TO DATE
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Depends.  What database are you using?

Comment: Does it make sense that I'm using a SQL database?

Comment: It's definitely Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the total quantity sold using `group by` in a subquery.  For example

```
select a.Item, a.Description, b.MonthQty, c.YearQty
from (
    select distinct Item, Description from TheTable
) a
left join (
    select Item, sum(Qty) as MonthQty
    from TheTable 
    where datediff(m,Date,getdate()) <= 1
    group by Item
) b on a.Item = b.Item
left join (
    select Item, sum(Qty) as YearQty
    from TheTable 
    where datediff(y,Date,getdate()) <= 1
    group by Item
) c on a.Item = c.Item
```

The method to limit the subquery to a particular date range differs per DBMS, this example uses the SQL Server `datediff` function.

Comment: Thanks again!  I got it to work using your code template except I used 
where date between 'date1' and 'date2'
instead of datediff (which wasn't working for me)
so I just have to enter my own date values...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "one month" is last month...

```
select item
       , description
       , sum (case when trunc(transaction_date, 'MM') 
                           = trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MM') 
                   then qty_sold
                   else 0
                   end) as sold_month
       , sum(qty_sold) as sold_ytd
from itm_sls
where transaction_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')
group by item, description
/
```

Comment: Nice query.  Small issue: if you query halfway a month, it would count the second half of last year's month towards this months total.

Comment: @Andomar.  Not sure what you mean.  The WHERE clause winnows out any transactions older than the start of the current year.

Comment: Ah right, +1 then :)  Turns out the question is for SQL Server, so truncate won't work, but the `sum(case when` would

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an idea of what you can do:

```
select 
    ITEM,
    DESCRIPTION, 
    QTY SOLD as MONTH, 
    ( select sum(QTY SOLD)
      from ITM_SLS
      where ITEM = I.ITEM
        AND YEAR = i.YEAR
     ) as YEAR TO DATE
from ITM_SLS I
```